# Need media-query solution for certain mobile browsers

Tags: android, css, mobile, media-queries, flexbox

I have a simple web app on a single page. I am currently struggling with getting it to look right across as many devices as possible.

**It looks fine on:**

- **acer laptop**(1366 x 768) on chrome, firefox and opera
- the **htc one x**(720 x 1280) on chrome, opera, firefox(couple of bugs)
- the **htc one**(1080 x 1920) on chrome and firefox(couple of bugs), haven't tested opera

**It looks screwed up on:**

- the **htc default browser**(tested on htc one x/one
- the **UC browser** (on htc one x)
- Safari on **iphone 4s**(up to date)
- and probably IE, though honestly, I haven't checked yet.

**screwed up == elements completely out of place and wrong sizes, seems as if main layout is being ignored**

The common denominators there are *chrome and firefox* anyway. It looks right on them, though firefox has some problems with my jquery it seems.

***The app itself is [here](http://band-name-generator.appspot.com/)***

**My question is:**

How can I get my app to look right on the browsers in the second list? I have searched the net for a solution to no avail. Everyone seems to have their own set of media queries that they claim works for them. So far, none have worked for me across the board.

I am currently using the following css, which works on the above mentioned devices and browsers:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {

    body {
    /*border: 1px dashed white;*/
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(background-soundproof.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    }

    div {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    }

    p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    }

    #main {
    /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    width:  40%;
    height: 99%;
    margin: auto;
    }

    #top {
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    height: 30.76923076923077%;
    } #top p {

    color:black;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 12px white,
                -2px 0 12px white,
               24px  0 50px #7D7DBD,
              -24px  0 50px #7D7DBD;

    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: Impact, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 80%;
    }

    #mid {
    /*border: 1px solid yellow;*/
    height: 15.384615384615385%;
    top: -7%;
    } #mid img {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: url(cool_pointer.png), pointer;
    }

    #bottom {
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    } #bottom p {
    text-shadow:0 0 12px white;
    font-family:Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:#7D7DBD;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    } #bottom img {
        display: none;
    }

    #footer {
    /*border: 1px dashed green;*/
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Courier;
    color: gray;    
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px), 
       only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)/*iphone 2g-4s*/ {

    body {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: black;
    }

    #main {
    width: 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape),
       only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) {

    #bottom {
        display:none;
    }

    #main {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    #top {
        top: 7%;
    }

    #mid {
        top: 6%;
    } #mid img {
        width: 30%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? Also, it looks like you are trying to use flexbox on your layout. I just read [this article](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/dont-use-flexbox-for-page-layout/) that explains why we shouldn't use flexbox on site structure, not that its gospel. Perhaps the issue with those phone browsers is that they don't support the flexbox module, or haven't been updated to newer versions to support the module.

Comment: You need *all* of this code to reproduce the problem?  Also, "looks screwed up" doesn't describe the problem.

Comment: @cimmanon you're right about my description, updated post. However, I think it might be relevant to have all the css there, as this may well be an issue with flexbox as dward suggested. I am currently testing this out

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're *actually* making use of Flexbox features that can't otherwise be reproduced, don't use Flexbox.  If you're providing prefixes, make sure you're providing *all* of the prefixes for every property.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
  /* line 10, ../sass/test.scss */
  body {
    /*border: 1px dashed white;*/
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(background-soundproof.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  /* line 24, ../sass/test.scss */
  div {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }

  /* line 30, ../sass/test.scss */
  p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }

  /* line 36, ../sass/test.scss */
  #main {
    /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    height: 99%;
    margin: auto;
  }

  /* line 46, ../sass/test.scss */
  #top {
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    height: 30.76923076923077%;
  }

  /* line 51, ../sass/test.scss */
  #top p {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 12px white, -2px 0 12px white, 24px  0 50px #7D7DBD, -24px  0 50px #7D7DBD;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: Impact, Sans-Serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 80%;
  }

  /* line 64, ../sass/test.scss */
  #mid {
    /*border: 1px solid yellow;*/
    height: 15.384615384615385%;
    top: -7%;
  }

  /* line 70, ../sass/test.scss */
  #mid img {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: url(cool_pointer.png), pointer;
  }

  /* line 77, ../sass/test.scss */
  #bottom {
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  }

  /* line 81, ../sass/test.scss */
  #bottom p {
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px white;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #7D7DBD;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* line 90, ../sass/test.scss */
  #bottom img {
    display: none;
  }

  /* line 94, ../sass/test.scss */
  #footer {
    /*border: 1px dashed green;*/
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Courier;
    color: gray;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* line 105, ../sass/test.scss */
  body {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: black;
  }

  /* line 110, ../sass/test.scss */
  #main {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape), only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* line 118, ../sass/test.scss */
  #bottom {
    display: none;
  }

  /* line 122, ../sass/test.scss */
  #main {
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  /* line 126, ../sass/test.scss */
  #top {
    top: 7%;
  }

  /* line 130, ../sass/test.scss */
  #mid {
    top: 6%;
  }

  /* line 134, ../sass/test.scss */
  #mid img {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```